# Why HTML table show like this in IE?

Tags: html, css, web

**Why first column width is too large where i set a fixed width in IE?.**

### My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head> 
<body>
<table  width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
    <td style="width:180px;"> 2 </td>
    <td>6 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" >
            lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        lskdjf lskfj lskjf lksfj lksf lksd flksflksfj lskf jlksf jlk        
    </td>   
</tr>    
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

### output:

[image: Output]
First column with is too large where i set the width of first column is 180px

```
<td style="width:180px;">
```

Comment: Can’t reproduce this; what version are you using? Also, it does seem like there is something else affecting this. If there was no width set for either column, it would equally distribute them making them 50% each, but your second column is far too small. Are you sure you that’s the exact code?

Comment: Can't reproduce this either : Have a look : http://jsfiddle.net/WzXEy/. Clear your caches perhaps?

Comment: Thank @loan: Please check in IE. http://jsfiddle.net/WzXEy. This not showing in IE.

Answer (score 1):

### Local Internet Explorer Mode "Fix"

I'm only able to reproduce this problem by changing IE's Document Mode to *IE5 quirks*, so I can only assume that's what you have your IE set to. By default, JSFiddle should load in *Standards* mode for whichever version you're using.

To fix this, simply hit <kbd>F12</kbd> on your keyboard to open IE's Developer Tools, then on the top bar of the UI that appears select Document Mode and change this to "Standards (Page Default)":

[image: IE Fix]

### IE5 Quirks Mode CSS Fix

Alternatively you can fix this in IE5 quirks mode simply by giving the table a fixed `table-layout`. In your CSS, simply add:

```css
table {
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Here is an [**updated JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WzXEy/1/).

Comment: @SarwarCSE the CSS, you mean? JSFiddle itself doesn't function properly on IE8. `table-layout` however does: http://caniuse.com/#search=table-layout

Comment: @SarwarCSE You can show the output of the fiddle in IE8 by appending `show` at the end of the URI. http://jsfiddle.net/WzXEy/1/show

Comment: @MrLister good shout, I wasn't aware of that. Looks like it's working as it should in IE8. :)